# Can we replace Local Storage with Cookies to store Tokens in NGRX based authentication?

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, local-storage, ngrx

***Auth Module.ts***

I would like to replace the local storage with cookies, can it be done ?

```
import { localStorageSync } from 'ngrx-store-localstorage';

const localStorageRules = {
  keys: [
    { auth: { deserialize: AuthState.deserialize } }
  ],
  rehydrate: true,
  storage: sessionStorage
};

export function localStorageSyncWrapper(reducer: any) {
  return localStorageSync(localStorageRules)(reducer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can install `ngx-cookie-service` for cookie store or remove or get..

for more information about npm pakage [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service)

Comment: Do you know how to keep browser tabs in sync using Cookies, NgRx, and RxJS ?